# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' with AlphabetScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_scroll_view in my project.

I receive data from backend and I parse it to list, but when I want to give it to above package as list I am getting this error:
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

This how my list is looking after parsing it:

```
[
{
 id: 1222,
 hidden: 1,
 nick_name: Saraya,
 id_fb: ,
 avatar: api/images/user/d4bfsd8769147.png,
 city: Toruń, Polska
}, 
{
 id: 2029,
 hidden: 1,
 etc.
}
```

and here is how I set it in my project:

```
AlphabetScrollView(
     list: (snapshot.data! as List).map((e) => AlphaModel(e)).toList(),
     selectedTextStyle: TextStyle(),
     unselectedTextStyle: TextStyle(),
```

I am not good with these Lists and Maps and I don't have idea what I need to change to get rid of this error.

Comment: Have you tried (snapshot.data!).map((e) => AlphaModel(e)).toList(),

Comment: @SuzZan yes, then I get this error ```The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Object'```

Comment: Ivo just answered the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `AlphaModel` expects a `String` but you are giving it a `Map`. Assuming you want to sort by nickname you can maybe do this instead:

```
 list: (snapshot.data! as List).map((e) => AlphaModel(e['nick_name']).toList(),
```

Comment: I need to list more than one thing, I need also city or avatar, it's possible to list more than one thing?

Comment: @KarolWiśniewski I'm not really familiar with the package, but I believe the AlphaModel is only used for the sorting. You can still use whatever you like for the rows I believe. I'm not 100% sure, you'll have to figure that out yourself